# Voltage controlled switch always closed in simulation

Tags: voltage, switches, simulation, ltspice

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw4mHw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have made the above (useless) schematic in LTspice. This after running into issues with a full schematic. The idea is to let e pulse train pass to the 2nd voltage controlled switch if and only if the Condensator connected to the positive input of SW1 reaches at least a voltage of 1.5V

However, this did not seem to work so in a test case I connected SW1 both the positive and negative input to ground. (Which to my knowledge should make SW1 always open). I have just a few days of experience with LTspice so it might be that I'm missing something. I have however googled and this seemed to be the right way to do it.

The full schematic in LTspice is given below

[image: LTspice Schematic]

This results in next simulation:

[image: Simulation of LTspice model]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? S1(SW2) is the MYSW and S2(SW1) is the UCSW. I can't seem to get it to work even if I change Vt to 15V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a 1k resistor across the control terminals of S1.

Now see if you can figure out why this makes a difference.

---

A voltage-controlled switch is just that — sensitive to voltage only. It doesn't care whether that voltage is connected through a 10M resistor or a 1m resistor — since it draws no current, there's no voltage drop across the contacts of S2 in either state.

Comment: So basically because these switches neither have a leak current nor an infinital high resistance (open chain ) there is no voltage drop over S2. If you introduce a 'leak current' by placing a resistor in parallel the issue does get solved, thanks @Dave Tweed